# Can I clear the bitmap from a static control by sending an STM_SETIMAGE message with a NULL bitmap handle

Tags: c, winapi

I'm writing a C program using the WinAPI. I created a dialog box with an image static control (created with the SS_BITMAP style so it displays bitmaps). I want to allow the user to be able to clear the bitmap from the static control.

I looked at the MSDN docs on image static controls and I didn't see any mention of clearing the image, and I don't see any message for doing that, so I had to come up with a solution. To clear the bitmap, I am sending the static control a STM_SETIMAGE message with a NULL as the handle to the bitmap, and it seems to work. But because I can't find any documentation on how to do this, I'm worried that this solution might not be reliable.

Here is the function that clears the bitmap (as you can guess "IDC_PICTUREBOX" is the id of the static control).

```
static BOOL      PerformEditDeleteCommand(HWND hwnd)
{
    HBITMAP hBitmapStored;

    if ((hBitmapStored=(HBITMAP)SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_PICTUREBOX, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)NULL)) != NULL)
        DeleteObject(hBitmapStored);

    return TRUE;
}
```

As I said before this solution appears to work, and by that I mean: 1. It doesn't crash. 2. The bitmap disappears from the static control. 3. The bitmap stored in the static control is returned as the result of the STM_SETIMAGE message (suggesting that the message is being processed and not just being ignored). 4. The static control continues to work after I clear the image (i.e. I can set and then clear bitmaps multiple times with no problems).

Before I tried this solution, I thought I would have to create a blank bitmap and set that as the static control's bitmap, but I don't want to do that if setting a NULL handle works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `NULL` is the correct way to clear the previous image from the control.